# How do I write proxy and implementation contracts that supports Chainlink functionality (Proxy Pattern via DELEGATECALL Solidity 0.6)

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have a Solidity smart contract which relies on Chainlink oracles for external data that has a lot of functionality code that does not need to be replicated on a per contract basis but does change the state of the contract instance, which is why I decided the proxy pattern using delegate calls makes the most sense. In the proxy pattern I only have to deploy the byte-code for my contracts functions once, and then all other instances of my contract will just delegate call to the implementation contract, and the only new information added to the block chain will be instance fields of that specific contract.

I am able to get an implementation contract deployed and point my deployed proxy to its functions, but then when I call the lock function on the proxy I fail the check `require(owner == msg.sender,"Owner only")` which doesnt make sense since delegate calls are supposed to pass `msg.sender` and I set the owner field to `msg.sender` in the proxy's constructor. If I remove the require, I can call the function without a revert but the `locked` and `debugAddr` fields are unchanged, even though the lock function should change them(I thought delegate call was executed in the context of the caller?). Does anyone know what is wrong with my proxy and implementation contracts? I can guess it is to do with memory layouts or the assembly im using to do delegate calls, but I am not yet on the level where I can use my googling skills to find out what is wrong, so if someone can spot where my proxy contract is incorrect/badly formatted please let me know.

Thanks,
Ben

**Lock function code snippet**

```
//Locks in the contract, buyer should have already provided data scientist an upload only API key and their model ID 
function lock() public returns (bool success)
{
    
    debugAddr = msg.sender;
    
    uint tempStamp = now;
    
    //THIS IS THE REQUIRE THAT FAILS WHEN IT SHOULDNT WHEN I UNCOMMENT THIS AND DEPLOY/RUN
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can lock contract.");
    
    //require(!locked, "Cannot lock contract that is already locked.");
    //require(buyer != address(0),"No buyer to lock.");
    //require(bytes(buyerModelName).length != 0,"No buyerModelName to lock.");
    //require((tempStamp - startTimestamp) < 158400,"Cannot lock contract that was entered by buyer over 44 hours ago.");
    //require((getWeekday(tempStamp) == 0) || (getWeekday(tempStamp) == 1 && getHour(tempStamp) < 14),"Contract can only be locked in between Sunday 00:00 UTC and Monday 14:00 UTC");
    
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    //require(link.balanceOf(address(this)) >= totalFee, "Contract requires 0.5 LINK total to operate once locked, current LINK balance is under 0.5.");
    
    locked = true;
    return true;
}
```

**Proxy contract with require commented**(also see the contract's txs, you can see me call lock):
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x1f805d559f6eb7d7b19bf0340db288503f448ae8
Implementation contract the proxy points to:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xfb41ea6452da396279cbd9d9d8c136121e38fab6

**Proxy contract with require uncommented**(also see the contract's txs, you can see me call lock, and the revert):
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2d59aa0c1dd9a77d592167c43f2e65adcb275bfe
Implementation contract the proxy points to:
0x20a1f27d69f7a257741eddaec433642194af0215

**Proxy Code and Implementation Code**

Referenced Code: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol

Proxy: https://github.com/benschreyer/Steak/blob/main/SteakQuarterly/ProxyPattern/SteakQuarterlyProxy.sol

*Important Note*  In my proxy I do not want to declare the contract as a ChainlinkClient since then ChainlinkClient's functions will be included in the proxy which is unnecessary as the implementation should have those methods already. Instead I only declare the fields and of ChainlinkClient on my own. I feel like this is a prime place for my implementation to be wrong, but I am not sure what needs to change/if this is even feasible

Implementation: https://github.com/benschreyer/Steak/blob/main/SteakQuarterly/ProxyPattern/SteakQuarterlyDelegate.sol

**EDIT: MINIMAL CODE EXAMPLE THAT STILL FAILS**
This contract should have the minimal requirements to be a proxy for a ChainlinkClient and only has the lock function and a constructor, I get the same revert on require(owner == msg.sender). If I remove the require, the call to lock on the proxy contract says confirmed, but the proxy's state variables remain unchanged (debugAddr is 0, locked stays false)

Here is the minimal example code(I deployed on remix IDE compiled 0.6.12, the proxy's lock function was called by using at address retrieval with the delegate code compiled so that the abi of the delegate is used): https://github.com/benschreyer/Steak/tree/main/MinimalCodeExample

**EDIT 2:**
If I remove the ChainlinkClient portion/fields of my proxy and implementation minimum examples as linked above, I get a proxy contract that works and can accept external function calls defined in the implementation contract as it should.

So my question now is how do I write proxy and implementation contract that supports Chainlink GET request functionality? What fields/constants/events/interfaces does my proxy need defined or imported and where should I define/import them to allow for Chainlink to work? For example if I wanted to have my contract retrieve the temperature in Paris from an API via Chainlink, but also be a proxy so that I do not have to redploy all its functions and save on gas price.

Anything I have tried so far(see minimal breaking example) does not work once I add Chainlink into the mix, as I am not sure about how to structure the Proxy contract class so that the storage of the proxy and the access/write of the delegate call to the implementation line up. Here is the minimal code that works after I remove Chainlink functionality:
https://github.com/benschreyer/Steak/tree/main/MinimalCodeExample/WorkingButNoChainlink
A version of my working example proxy/implementation pattern contracts but with Chainlink functionality, or pointers on what fields/events/cosntant the proxy contract needs in order for it to make calls to oracles would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a minimum example here? Do you get this same problem using only the proxy? Or do you only get the issue when working with Chainlink contracts? A lot of code here to go through to find the error.

Comment: I added minimal Chainlink proxy and implementation solidity classes to the original post, should be much easier to debug like you mentioned

Comment: Seems like inheriting a class for the fields of ChainlinkClient instead of declaring them may be what makes this work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the fields of ChainlinkClient in your proxy class, write a class ChainlinkClientStorage that holds the fields of ChainlinkClient, then declare your Proxy as inheriting from ChainlinkClientStorage

https://github.com/benschreyer/Steak/blob/main/SteakQuarterly/ProxyPattern/ChainlinkClientStorage.sol

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol

```
contract MyProxy is ChainlinkClientStorage, MyContractStorage{}
```